# How can I find the integration of $ \int {\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}\right)}^{1/2}dx $...?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$ \int {\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}\right)}^{1/2}dx $$

Any suggestion on how to solve it is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to set as $t$ the arg of the square root?

Comment: Can you plz show me

Comment: Wondering, is this a problem from a text book?

Comment: what have u tried

Comment: hint...substitute $\sqrt{x}=\cos2\theta$

Comment: Or just set $t=\sqrt{(1-\sqrt{x})/(1+\sqrt{x})}$, and you will get a rational function.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Let $\sqrt x=\cos2t\implies0\le2t\le\dfrac\pi2$

$$\dfrac{1-\sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}=\tan^2t\implies\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}}=+\tan t$$

$$x=\cos^22t\implies dx=-2\cos2t\sin2t\ dt$$

$$ \int {\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}\right)}^{1/2}dx=-4\int\cos2t\sin^2t\ dt$$

$$=2\int\cos2t(\cos2t-1)dt$$

$$=\int(1+\cos4t-2\cos2t)dt$$

Can you take it from here?